# Can attacker circumvent a htaccess 'deny from all' command

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, whitelist

I applied an htaccess file to the /administrator directory of a joomla website that is supposed to whitelist only my local ip address and my public ip address .

However, it appears that a new user account was created within that joomla account a couple of months after I applied the white list.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 77.##.##.###
```

Can someone offer a theory on how this is possible?

Comment: You can create a user through the front end, even if there isn't a menu item for that, assuming that you don't have that disabled. What is the new user's groups?

Comment: ... I'll check it tonight ... sorry I haven't gotten back to you. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can be created via front-end, even if you don't have a registration link or form there. Registration might be accessed by going to: `index.php?option=com_users&view=registration`

You can disable this option in Joomla back-end. To do so go to: `System -> Global Configuration -> Users Manager` and turn `Allow User Registration` to NO.